# Combine multiple related records into a string

Tags: filemaker

I'd like to automate our license code management using FileMaker but can't figure out one thing.

Say I have two DBs: `Machines` and `Licenses`. The two files look like this (all fields are text)

```
Machines
  serialNo
  macAddr

Licenses
  macAddr
  licType
  licQty
```

The two files are related/connected via the "macAddr" field

So example content for `Machines` might look like:

```
SerialNo macAddr
17801    84:8f:69:f5:0C:B5
17802    84:8f:69:D5:CC:B0
```

And Licenses could contain

```
macAddr           licQty licType
84:8f:69:f5:0C:B5   1    Base
84:8f:69:f5:0C:B5   2    Editor
84:8f:69:f5:0C:B5   1    Admin
84:8f:69:D5:CC:B0   1    Base
84:8f:69:D5:CC:B0   10   Editor
```

**The Question**

Given the data above, I'd like to create one report layout which creates one line per MAC Address (or serial number) and summarizes the licenses for each machine in **a single string**.
ie,

```
84:8f:69:f5:0C:B5,Base:1,Editor:2,Admin:1
84:8f:69:D5:CC:B0,Base:1,Editor:10
```

I've fiddled with portals on both files but can never get the right summary.